# Persisting programmatically added preferences in android

Tags: java, android, preferences

basically what I want is this:

-> I have some settings that (of course) can be modified by the user, on of it is the 'number of cubes'
-> There is an other setting which depends on this setting (movement)
----> if there is one cube the setting is disabled (this works)
----> if there are two cubes there are two options for movement and the setting is enabled (this works too)
----> if there are four cubes there needs to be a choice added for movement and here lays my problem:

I can programmatically change the value of the ListPreference to add this setting but:
-> when the user sets the added value "paired"
and
-> (s)he moves away from the settings, the setting is read correctly
however
-> when the users moves back to the settings the setting is set to the first element of the list(synchronized), not being the choice (s)he made earlier
-> the setting (paired) is remembered by the SharedPreferences instance which I get by calling:

```
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

but when moving to the settings again shows the wrong value for the setting (which nobody wants)

How do I persist a programmatically added value?

Of course the reason is that I read the preferences.xml again when the Activity is resumed, but I don't know how to persist the choice made by the user when the Activity is recreated.

This is my code: (the two methods that matter)

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("SA", "onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    updateLists();
}

private void updateLists() {
    Log.d("SA", "updateLists");
    Preference numberOfCubesPref = findPreference("numberOfCubes");
    Preference tupleTypePref = findPreference("tuple");
    Preference movementTypePref = findPreference("movement_type");
    Preference pictureDistributionPref = findPreference("distribution_of_pictures");

    ListPreference numberOfCubesListPref = (ListPreference) numberOfCubesPref;

    if(numberOfCubesListPref.getEntry() == null){
        numberOfCubesListPref.setValueIndex(0); 
    }

    numberOfCubesPref.setSummary(numberOfCubesListPref.getEntry());

    ListPreference movementTypeListPref = (ListPreference) movementTypePref;

    if(movementTypeListPref.getEntry() == null){
        movementTypeListPref.setValueIndex(0); 
    }

    if (numberOfCubesListPref.getEntry().equals("Four")) {
        movementTypePref.setEnabled(true);
        pictureDistributionPref.setEnabled(true);

        CharSequence[] oldEntries = movementTypeListPref.getEntries();

        if (oldEntries.length == 2) {

            Log.d("SA","length is twoo");

            CharSequence[] newEntries = new CharSequence[oldEntries.length + 1];

            newEntries[0] = oldEntries[0];
            newEntries[1] = "Paired";
            newEntries[2] = oldEntries[1];

            movementTypeListPref.setEntries(newEntries);

            CharSequence[] oldEntryValues = movementTypeListPref
                    .getEntryValues();

            CharSequence[] newEntryValues = new CharSequence[oldEntryValues.length + 1];

            newEntryValues[0] = oldEntryValues[0];
            newEntryValues[1] = "Paired";
            newEntryValues[2] = oldEntryValues[1];

            movementTypeListPref.setEntryValues(newEntryValues);
        }

    } else if (numberOfCubesListPref.getEntry().equals("Two")) {
        movementTypePref.setEnabled(true);
        pictureDistributionPref.setEnabled(true);

        CharSequence[] oldEntries = movementTypeListPref.getEntries();

        if (oldEntries.length == 3) {

            CharSequence[] newEntries = new CharSequence[oldEntries.length - 1];

            newEntries[0] = oldEntries[0];
            newEntries[1] = oldEntries[2];

            movementTypeListPref.setEntries(newEntries);

            CharSequence[] oldEntryValues = movementTypeListPref
                    .getEntryValues();

            CharSequence[] newEntryValues = new CharSequence[oldEntryValues.length - 1];

            newEntryValues[0] = oldEntryValues[0];
            newEntryValues[1] = oldEntryValues[2];

            movementTypeListPref.setEntryValues(newEntryValues);
        }
    } else {
        movementTypePref.setEnabled(false);
        pictureDistributionPref.setEnabled(false);
    }

    ListPreference pictureDistributionListPref = (ListPreference) pictureDistributionPref;
    ListPreference tupleTypeListPref = (ListPreference) tupleTypePref;

    if(tupleTypeListPref.getEntry() == null){
        tupleTypeListPref.setValueIndex(0); 
    }

    CharSequence[] entries = pictureDistributionListPref.getEntries();

    CharSequence target, replacement;

    if (tupleTypeListPref.getEntry().equals("Two of the same kind")) {
        target = "Triplet";
        replacement = "Pair";
    } else {
        target = "Pair";
        replacement = "Triplet";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        entries[i] = ((String) entries[i]).replace(target, replacement);
    }

    pictureDistributionListPref.setEntries(entries);

    if(pictureDistributionListPref.getEntry() == null){
        pictureDistributionListPref.setValueIndex(0); 
    }

    tupleTypePref.setSummary(tupleTypeListPref.getEntry());
    movementTypePref.setSummary(movementTypeListPref.getEntry());
    pictureDistributionPref.setSummary(pictureDistributionListPref.getEntry());
}
```

and my preferences.xml (relevant piece):

```
        <ListPreference
    android:dialogTitle="@string/choose_movement_type"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:entries="@array/movement_type_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/movement_type_values"
    android:key="movement_type"
    android:title="@string/movement_type" />
```

and strings.xml: (relevant piece)

```
        <string name="movement_type">Movement type</string>
<string name="choose_movement_type">How do you want to control the cubes?</string>

<string-array name="movement_type_entries">
    <item>Synchronized</item>
    <item>Independent</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="movement_type_values">
    <item>Synchronized</item>
    <item>Independent</item>
</string-array>
```

The activity is called from within an other activity like this:

```
            settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SettingsActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

any help/comments/tips are welcome :)

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are modifying the preference temporary. to save the prefrences and be sure it remains the same, use [sharedPreferencesTurbo](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo)

Comment: solely based upon the README.md content this class just selects/puts values with a key reference, I want to also add new keys and persist them in the settings (without reloading the settings.xml)

Comment: to my knowledge, what you're tying to do is not possible. Because you're trying to modify the apk. (The xml file was created while making the app and cannot be modified after the app is compiled.) what you can do is save the xml file to the phones external storage and then read/modify it from there. You should re-orient your self on working with Shared preferences after initialy reading from the default xml pref.